# I'm attempting to take a ready player me model from blender to mixamo but the uploded model keeps showing up grey/white

Tags: uv, texture-painting, mixamo

I could use some help

blender version: 3.4
I've taken a ready player me model and imported it as a glb file scaled it down ALL down slightly and exported it as a FBX file. when I attempt to upload the FBX file into mixamo the model looks perfect but minus all the uv color just grey white.

I started over only this time i saved as a .blend file and went to File->External Data->pressed Unpack Resources and selected Use files in current directory (create when necessary) and then exported it as FBX file. uploaded it into mixamo and I'm still having the same issue could some one help me please [image: mixamo upload]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures